# Making commands non-case sensitive for a discord bot

Tags: discord.py

I have a command called repeat, I'd like users to be able to call it via typing $Repeat as well as $repeat just incase they get confused by capitilization. If possible I'd like them to also be able to call it with $rep and $Rep as well.

```
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='type a sequence of words seperated by spaces and they will be repeated back to you as a sequence of messages')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    print("repeating")
    await asyncio.gather(*[ctx.send(line) for line in lines])
```

I can't see a way of doing that from the documentation - except creating commands rep, Rep and Repeat that call the same function - but that feels inelegant.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a `discord.ext.commands.Bot` instance, you can achieve case insensitive matching by specifying [`case_insensitive=True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive) when instantiating your bot

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(prefix='$', case_insensitive=True)
```

The second can be achieved by means of passing the [`aliases`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.aliases) parameter to your command decorator

```py
@bot.command(name='repeat', aliases=['rep'], help='...')
```